# Why is my custom Texture2D blurry?

Tags: unity, textures

Have some WWW object downloading a .PNG image.

```
((SpriteRenderer)renderer).sprite = Sprite.Create(request.texture, 
         new Rect(0,0,100,100));
```

My sprite looks fine.

Now, let's be a bit redundant and create a `Texture2D` out of the bytes from the download:

```
Texture2D t = new Texture2D(100,100);
t.LoadImage(request.bytes);
((SpriteRenderer)renderer).sprite = Sprite.Create(t, new Rect(0,0,t.width,t.height));
```

Technically, this should produce something identical to the above snippet. However, the sprite is blurry (as in, low quality).

I suppose it is when calling `LoadImage`. What may be causing this?

Comment: I know that textures loaded in the editor can be blurry if MipMapping is on. It should be OFF for 2d textures. Not sure how that relates to loaded from code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing  the [filterMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-filterMode.html) to Point:

```
t.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
```

Comment: Changing the filter mode worked, although it was `Trilinear` the one yielding the best results (not sure why).

Comment: I'm glad that sorted it out.  I guess I was visualising pixel art (usually best with point filtering) while the ideal mode will vary with art style.